# I cannot get my ImageIcon to display

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

This is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Option extends JFrame{ 

ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("image.png");
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("image2.png");
JButton testBut = new JButton(img);
JButton testBut2 = new JButton(img2);
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

public Option(){
    super("Swing Window");
    setSize( 500,200 );
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pnl.add(testBut);
    pnl.add(testBut2);
    add(pnl);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Option gui = new Option();
}
}
```

I have got both the images in the same directory as the class file and the buttons are showing up blank. I am quite new to Java so I cannot think of any reason why this is wrong.

**EDIT**

The images are in the same directory as the Option class

Comment: Where are the images stored, relative to the `Option` class?  You might like to have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: The images are in the same directory as the Option class

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I managed to fix it. I used an URL like you said, which at first didn't work, but all I had to do was simply refresh the project, allowing the png files to show up. THANKS EVERYONE!

Answer (score 2):

> "The images are in the same directory as the Option class"

`ImageIcon(String)` is trying to find the named images within the context of the working directory (from where the program was executed) and it will fail, because the images actually don't exist there.

The images are contained within the applications context (when your application is jared, the images will emebeded within the Jar).

Instead, you should try using...

```
img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image.png"));
```

from within the constructor of the class.  This will try and look for the images, relative to the package of your the class calling `getResource` within the context of your application's classpath

I would also encourage the use of `ImageIO.read` of `ImageIcon` for two reasons, one, the image is guaranteed to be loaded when the method is called (rather then been loaded in some background thread) and two, it will throw an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded for some reason, which is far more helpful

Have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can add in code something like that also:

---

`setIconImage(new ImageIcon(new File("icona.png").toString()).getImage());`